# <div> element acting like it's behind something invisible

Tags: html, css, click, cursor

I have the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/L86xV/

The main excerpts are:

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="innerwrapper">
        <div id="nav">
            <div id="about" class="menu1">About</div>
            <div id="aboutsub">
                <div id="team" class="menu2">Team</div>
                <div id="experience" class="menu2">Experience</div>
                <div id="difference" class="menu2">Difference</div>
            </div>
            <div id="work" class="menu1">Work</div>
            <div id="portfolio" class="menu1">Portfolio</div>
            <div id="contact" class="menu1">Contact</div>
        </div>
        <div id="outerviewer">
            <div id="innerviewer">This is where the main text goes.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#outerviewer {
    float: right;
    width: 576px;
    height: 700px;
    background: #63c5ff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
    -moz-border-radius: 60px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    z-index: 100;
}
#innerviewer {
    width: 506px;
    height: 630px;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
    -moz-border-radius: 60px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    outline: 0px solid black;
    padding: 25px;
}
.menu2 {
    position: absolute;
    background-image:url('../img/BTF_Tab_Sub.png');
    background: purple;
    width: 80px;
    height: 42px;
    left: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

It was my hope that the items with the class `menu2` would act like those with `menu1` and change cursor to the pointer.  However, they don't, and adding javascript to the buttons returns no events.

I've tried messing with z-index to no avail, can anyone suggest why the `menu2` items aren't clickable and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re: `position:relative;`, the z-index is only applied to positioned elements (relative, absolute or fixed).

The [w3 wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index) makes a note that z-index

> • Only works on positioned elements(position: absolute;, position: relative; or position: fixed;).

And the [w3 CSS2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index) states that z-index

> *Applies to:* positioned elements

Answer (score 1):

It seems I had to set

```
#outerviewer
{
    position: relative;
}
```

I don't know why, but if someone explains it well enough, I will give them the tick to help others know why.

Answer (score 0):

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L86xV/1/)

You had a negative z-index on the sub-menu.

My changes:

```
#about {

    z-index:0;
}
#aboutsub {

    z-index: 1;
}

#innerviewer {
    z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: I've done similar, but now the `menu2` item comes in front of the `outerviewer`, which it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

When I take out z-index: -1 in the aboutsub div, the desired cursor shows on the purple submenu.

Comment: I did the same, and even though `#outerviewer` is set to `z-index: 100`, it is behind the `menu2` items.  Really annoying.